# Sitecore add insert new option to droplink field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, extending

I'm using sitecore and Content Authors want to improve their experience by adding "Insert new" option to a droplink field (instead of going to the datasource location and create a new item, and then select the new item from the droplink). 
Do I need to create a new field type to extend the droplink field or is there any other field type that can achieve this?

Comment: You can try **unbound droplist**: http://getfishtank.ca/blog/new-sitecore-field-unbound-droplist . It works with Sitecore 6, but with some minor tricks show work for Sitecore 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't exist such a functionality out of the box. 
You have two possibilities:

1. To create a custom droplink field for creating new items
2. To use edit frame in page editor and when is clicking edit frame click data source item is open and then you can add or delete new items for droplink field.

For more about edit frames you can read here :

1. https://www.cmsbestpractices.com/how-to-properly-use-sitecore-edit-frames/
2. http://blog.jan.hebnes.dk/2011/12/using-sitecore-editframe-with-datasource.html

Comment: Do you have any example of the 1st option? I created a new field and I'm trying to extend the Droplink field but I'm having some issues. I've played with EditFrames before and they are powerful but for this case I reckon that the 1st option would be better for this scenario.

Comment: You can check with reflector or dot peek decompiling Sitecore code  how it was made general link field and droplink field